# Prettify Not Rendering Code

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get the google prettify working on my site. So far ive,

Loaded the Js at the beginning of the page via

```
<script src="/templates/yoo_digit/styles/fir3net20/js/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

Which I can see is being loaded. And also add some code with the ..

```
<pre class="prettify">code</pre>
```

.. tags. I can see that the js is being loaded and there are no js errors via firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the class name is "prettyprint" and not "prettify" change your html to this

```
<pre class="prettyprint">code</pre>
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/64pat/

Reference :-https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted